# How to align a <ol> to the bottom of the containing <div>?

Tags: css

I have the following:

```
ol.progress-tracker {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    /*
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    */
        }
```

If I try the commented code, it messes up my other styling and I'm not sure why.  Is there another way to push this thing to the bottom in a responsive-design-friendly way?  My fiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4mABB/

Comment: Your fiddle cannot work. For example, your html code has no `#browser-body`.

Comment: Linus - is this needed to demo the problem?  Kyle: yes, I have.  Even if I try it in the fiddle, the bar doesn't get pushed down.

Comment: Depends on the problem you have. For instance the `position: relative` on your container div is ignored.

Comment: @linusCaldwell jsfiddle will take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you position a block element absolutely, it looses it's default property of using the whole space horizontally. You would have to specify a width yourself:

```
ol.progress-tracker { width: 300px; /* or whatever */ }
```

Comment: Thanks Linus - I just specified width to be 100% and it's got its look/feel back, but it's no longer centered.  I have display inline-block for the ol and text-align center for the parent div, any idea why?

Comment: scratch that - I specified bottom and left positions and it lined up.  I appreciate the help!